# Cannot create a WPF .NET core application

Tags: wpf, .net-core

Trying to create a simple .NET core WPF application and VS2019 simply wont have it.
I am getting the following error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> To create this project type, go to Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | > .NET Core and check “Use preview
> versions of the .NET Core SDK”

When I try to go and check that flag it is not there.
Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Have you installed .NET Core 3 preview 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog text is currently incorrect. Check under Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features.

[Visual Studio 2019, setting to enable .NET Core SDK previews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNNRC.png)