# .NET Core 3 Preview WPF error: "To create this project type, go to Tools..."

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I installed .NET Core 3 Runtime and SDK Preview 9 today to make a WPF application. However, when I try to create it, I get the following error: "To create this project type, go to Tools | Options | Environment | Preview Features and check "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK" (similar to [Cannot create a WPF .NET core application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073084/cannot-create-a-wpf-net-core-application))

Te only problem is that I have this feature enabled, and I restarted the computer as it suggests, but I still get the same error message.

[image]

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed with SDK 3.0.100-preview9 and Runtime 3.0.0-preview9, running on Windows 10.

Comment: I can reproduce your issue. In the meantime, you can create a new WPF project that targets .NET Core from a Visual Studio Command Prompt using the `dotnet new wpf` command.

Comment: Thanks, it works from the command line.

Comment: Or you can refer this: How to: [Port a WPF desktop app to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/wpf#create-a-new-sdk-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the exact issue. What worked for me was to update Visual Studio 2019 (was a couple of updates behind). 
Confirmed it works on v.16.3.0

Comment: It really works in v16.3.0 (my version when the problem occured was 16.2.5)

Comment: sorry for the issue and yes 16.3 will resolve it. We also had a small problem with WPF Core designer not working but its fixed in 16.3.1 servicing release that is already out.

Comment: Hey Dmitry! Speaking of Designers, first to say-  I'm incredibly glad for the opportunity to use an pre-release version of the Designer for Windows Forms for .NET Core 3.0!! 

To report a slight issue there - > while using the toolbox, if you don't explicitly hold and drag the item, but rather click and paste it somewhere, there is a 50/50 chance that it will not be registered in the designer, but will still appear in the code behind. Also it will break the designer horrifically. Other than that it was a smooth use so far!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue even after installing the latest updates.
My PATH Environmental Variable at the System Level was missing the CORE directory `C:\Program Files\dotnet`